# How to inject in provider in strict mode

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to run [this](http://engineering.talis.com/articles/client-side-error-logging/) example but I have difficulties with injection of the $exceptionHandler inside the exceptionLoggingService provider because I am in `strictDi = true` mode and I get an [$exceptionHandler is not using explicit annotation and cannot be invoked in strict mode](http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.0/$injector/strictdi?p0=%24exceptionHandler) error.
Some suggestions how can I perform the injection in provider?

```
var loggingModule = angular.module('loggingModule', []);

loggingModule.factory('traceService', function() {
    return ({
        print: printStackTrace
    });
});

loggingModule.provider("$exceptionHandler", {
    $get: function(exceptionLoggingService) {
        return (exceptionLoggingService);
    }
});

loggingModule.factory("exceptionLoggingService", ["$log", "$window", "traceService", 
    function($log, $window, traceService) {
        function error(exception, cause) {
            //
        }
        return (error);
    }
]);
```

Actually I've managed to run the code this way but I really need to use the above example.

```
loggingModule.provider('$exceptionHandler', function ExceptionLoggingService() {
    this.$get = ['$log', '$window', 'traceService',
        function($log, $window, traceService) {
            function error(exception, cause) {
                //
            }
            return (error);
        }
    ];
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried providing explicit annotation which is described in the error you posted a link to?

```
loggingModule.provider("$exceptionHandler", {
    $get: ['exceptionLoggingService', function(exceptionLoggingService) {
        return (exceptionLoggingService);
    }]
});
```

Comment: Hmm actually I didn't exactly this way. I thought that the provider doesn't accept inline injections but now I see that I've done just that in my second code snippet.
Thank you